# YADCF Datatables Server-Side only return current page from autocomplete filtering

Tags: php, datatables, yadcf

first of all, this is awesome plugin when using with latest datatables v1.10.13 and yadcf v0.9

Hi have issues, where autocomplete filtering only return current page only,

Here my server_roccessing.php,

```
<?php

    $requestData= $_REQUEST;

      $columns = array(
          0 => 'test01',
          1 => 'test02',
          2 => 'test03',
          3 => 'test04',
          4 => 'test05'
      );

    // getting total number records without any search
    $sql = "SELECT id,test01,test01,test02,test03,test04, test05 ";
    $sql.=" FROM sample";
    $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die("server_processing.php: getData");
    $totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    $totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.

    $sql = "SELECT id,test01,test01,test02,test03,test04, test05  ";
    $sql.=" FROM sample WHERE 1 = 1";

    // getting records as per search parameters
    if( !empty($requestData['columns'][0]['search']['value']) ){   //name
      $sql.=" AND test01 LIKE '".$requestData['columns'][0]['search']['value']."%' ";
    }
    if( !empty($requestData['columns'][1]['search']['value']) ){   //name
      $sql.=" AND test02 LIKE '".$requestData['columns'][1]['search']['value']."%' ";
    }
    if( !empty($requestData['columns'][2]['search']['value']) ){   //name
      $sql.=" AND test03 LIKE '".$requestData['columns'][2]['search']['value']."%' ";
    }
    if( !empty($requestData['columns'][3]['search']['value']) ){   //name
      $sql.=" AND test04 LIKE '".$requestData['columns'][3]['search']['value']."%' ";
    }
    if( !empty($requestData['columns'][4]['search']['value']) ){   //name
      $sql.=" AND test05 LIKE '".$requestData['columns'][4]['search']['value']."%' ";
    }

    $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die("server_processing.php: getData");
    $totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result.

    if ($requestData['length'] > 0 ){
        $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."   LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
    } else {
        $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."   ";
    }

    $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die("server_processing.php: getData");


    $data = array();
    while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array

      $nestedData=array();

      $nestedData[] = $row["test01"];
      $nestedData[] = $row["test02"];
      $nestedData[] = $row["test03"];
      $nestedData[] = $row["test04"];
      $nestedData[] = $row["test05"];

      $data[] = $nestedData;

    }

    $json_data = array(
          "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw.
          "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
          "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
          "data"            => $data   // total data array
          );

    echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format

    ?>
```

Below where YADCF(0.9) takes action alongside Datatables 1.10.13

```
      var dataTable = $('#mygrid').DataTable( {
      "serverSide": true,
      "processing": true,
      "ajax":{
        url :"server_processing.php", // json datasource
        type: "post",  // method  , by default get
      }
    });

  yadcf.init(dataTable, [{
    column_number: 0,
    filter_type: "auto_complete"
  }, {
    column_number: 1,
    filter_type: "multi_select",
    select_type: "chosen"
  }, {
    column_number: 2,
    filter_type: 'auto_complete'
  }, {
    column_number: 3,
    filter_type: 'auto_complete'
  }, {
    column_number: 4,
    filter_type: 'auto_complete'
  }]);
```

Filtering based on text work like charm, but, when filtering based on autocomplete, it only return current page only..

TQ

Comment: If by current page only you referring the available options in the filter then it means that you are not sending  all available options(of the entire pages) to the yadcf filters (you mist add filter options along with your datatable rows

Comment: But why, when filtering based on text,(using your function), it works, while using autocomplete function it doesnt? Please help me out, using above scripts..tq

Comment: Because text filter does not require predefined options while auto complete and select do, look through previous yadcf question on stackoverflow related to php on what to do

Comment: see this answer, it should help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/41769652/617373

Comment: Tq, but still the same :(